# How can you retrieve building height information from the HERE API?

Tags: rest, here-api

I've seen the option to enable building extrusions based on height data in the SDKs, but I can't find any way to just simply retrieve building height + level information directly from the HERE REST API for a specific lat/lon?

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, the height information is being used to render 3D map and mSDK is supporting 3D Vector maps based on this parameter.
By comparison, HERE REST API is just supporting 2D map tile so the height information is not available through it.